# Behaviour and Limit of Cumulative Distribution as Variance Grows to Infinity

Tags: probability-distributions, asymptotics, probability-limit-theorems

Please suggest:

## Question 1)

What are some reasonable assumptions regarding the limit of the Cumulative Distribution as the Variance grows to infinity.

$$
\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow\infty} F\left(t,\sigma\right) = \text{??}
$$

## Question 2)

Also, is it a reasonable assumption to expect that the cumulative distribution will decrease in value with growing variance, as shown below?

$$\frac{\partial F(t,\sigma)}{\partial\sigma}\leq0$$

Here, $F(t,\sigma)$ are a family of distributions with parameter governed by $\sigma$, the variance. If helpful, we can make another simplifying assumption that $t\geq0$.

Please note, the questions are not specific to any particular distribution, but any general distribution and what are some valid forms of this limit and the behaviour of the distribution as variance increases.

Please point out any specific references on this topic and also list any additional assumptions made to arrive at any results.

Please let me know if the question is not clear or if you need any further information.

Comment: Presumably you're dealing with some family of distributions parametrized by the variance, but the answer will depend a lot on which family it is.  I doubt that there's anything meaningful to say in general.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, For example, if we consider the normal distribution or even the uniform distribution, as the variance increases, we can expect the cumulative distribution to decrease. So would that be a valid constraint or assumption on the behavior of the cumulative distribution. So there a few families where this holds? Please could you point out any error or flaw in this line of reasoning. Also, what about when variance grows to infinity?

Comment: That said, one useful class of examples is where the random variable depends linearly on the parameter: $X(\sigma) = \sigma X(1)$.  Note of course that the variance of $\sigma X(1)$ is $\sigma^2 \text{Var}(X(1))$, 
while $$F(t, \sigma) = \mathbb P(\sigma X \le t) = \mathbb P(X \le t/\sigma) = F(t/\sigma, 1)$$

Comment: If $X(1)$ is standard normal, $F(t,\sigma)$ will then decrease with $\sigma$ **if** $t > 0$, but increase with $\sigma$ if $t < 0$

Comment: @RobertIsrael, much appreciative of your clarifications. So for a positive valued random variable, say a log normal distribution, it would be a reasonable assumption that, $$\frac{\partial F(t,\sigma)}{\partial\sigma}\leq0$$ Can we assume that, say for any general continuous distribution,
$$
\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow\infty} F\left(t,\sigma\right) >0, t>0
$$ Perhaps, I am unclear unsaying this ...

Answer (score 1):

One example is the normal distribution with expected value $0.$

Let $Z\sim N(0,1).$ Then $\sigma Z\sim N(0,\sigma^2).$ Let $F$ be the c.d.f. of $\sigma Z.$ Then
$$
F(t) = \Pr(\sigma Z\le t) = \Pr\left( Z \le \frac t \sigma \right).
$$
As $\sigma$ increases, then $t/\sigma\quad \begin{cases} \text{increases to } 0 & \text{if } t<0,  \\ \text{decreases to } 0 & \text{if } t>0. \end{cases}$

Therefore $F(t)\quad \begin{cases} \text{increases to } 1/2 & \text{if } t<0, \\ \text{decreases to } 1/2 & \text{if }t>0. \end{cases}$

Comment: Can we assume that, say for any general continuous distribution,
$$
\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow\infty} F\left(t,\sigma\right) >0, t>0
$$ Perhaps, I am unclear unsaying this ...

Comment: A distribution is _a_ distribution; it is _one_ distibution. One cannot speak of the c.d.f. changing unless one is speaking of more than one distribution. You need to specify a particular family of distributions before one can know what question you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. If we say that $F(t,\sigma)$ are a family of distributions with parameter governed by $\sigma$, would that be a reasonable place to start? I will add this clarification in the question as well, if you think it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a few more examples for Question 2, in addition to the clarifications by Robert Israel and Michael Hardy.

## Example 1:

The derivative of the cumulative distribution of a uniformly distributed
variable, having support $t\in\left[a,b\right]\;;0\leq a,b<\infty$,
with respect to the standard deviation (variance) is less than zero.
$$
F\left(t\right)=\left(\frac{t-a}{b-a}\right)\equiv F\left(t,\sigma_{D}\right)\propto\frac{\left(t-a\right)}{\sigma_{D}}\;\because\sigma_{D}^{2}=\frac{\left(b-a\right)^{2}}{12}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial F\left(t,\sigma_{D}\right)}{\partial\sigma_{D}}\propto-\frac{\left(t-a\right)}{\sigma_{D}^{2}}\Longrightarrow\frac{\partial F\left(t,\sigma_{D}\right)}{\partial\sigma_{D}}\leq0
$$

## Example 2:

The derivative of the cumulative distribution of a log-normally distributed
variable, $\ln Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$, with
respect to the variance is less than zero in the region where, $y>e^{\mu}$.
$$
F\left(t,\sigma\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\left(\frac{\ln t-\mu}{\sigma}\right)}e^{-\frac{y^{2}}{2}}dy=\Phi\left(\frac{\ln t-\mu}{\sigma}\right)
$$

$$
\text{Var}\left(Y\right)=e^{2\mu+2\sigma^{2}}-e^{2\mu+\sigma^{2}}\;;\frac{\partial\text{Var}\left(Y\right)}{\partial\sigma}=2\sigma\left\{ 2e^{2\mu+2\sigma^{2}}-e^{2\mu+\sigma^{2}}\right\} >0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial F\left(t,\sigma\right)}{\partial\text{Var}\left(Y\right)}=\frac{\partial F\left(t,\sigma\right)}{\partial\sigma}\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial\text{Var}\left(Y\right)}\propto e^{-\frac{\left(\ln t-\mu\right)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}\left\{ -\left(\frac{\ln t-\mu}{\sigma^{2}}\right)\right\} 
$$
$$\Longrightarrow\frac{\partial F\left(t,\sigma\right)}{\partial\text{Var}\left(Y\right)}\leq0\;;\text{ When }\left(\ln t-\mu\right)>0
$$

Perhaps simply written as,
$$
\frac{\partial F\left(t,\sigma\right)}{\partial\sigma}\propto e^{-\frac{\left(\ln t-\mu\right)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}\left\{ -\left(\frac{\ln t-\mu}{\sigma^{2}}\right)\right\} \Longrightarrow\frac{\partial F\left(t,\sigma\right)}{\partial\sigma}\leq0\;;\text{ When }\left(\ln t-\mu\right)>0
$$